# JTAG daisy chain or multiplexer?

Tags: jtag

I'm about to dive into a new topic which interests me and as such I'm at the fork to decide between [daisy chaining](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/17834/design-advice-when-daisy-chaining-multiple-jtag-devices) several devices or to use a [multiplexer](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ds26900.pdf). Finally, I want to flash µCs via JTAG. I've seen that both options are available but which is advisable?
The concept is part of a [CI/CD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CI/CD) pipeline where firmware code is automatically built and tested and in the end flashed to the µCs.
The number of devices will usually be around 6-8 and with 16 as maximum.

Comment: I’d have thought it would be simpler to have individual jtag dongles for each. No custom shenanigans required.

Comment: dongles make it impossible to use it for automation, or?

Comment: JTAG can be used in many ways. If it is used for boundary scanning, then it is usually daisy chained. If it is used for an MCU test port, you probably don't want to daisy chain.

Comment: it's actually the latter, I want to load firmware onto the mcus and run some tests with it, no scans or the like. So you advice a switch then?